# Where does the newline come from in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

In Python when I do

```
print "Line 1 is"
print "big"
```

The output I get is

```
Line 1 is
big
```

Where does the newline come from? And how do I type both statements in the same line using two print statements?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`print` adds a newline by default.  To avoid this, use a trailing `,`:

```
print "Line 1 is",
print "big"
```

The `,` will still yield a space.  To avoid the space as well, either concatenate your strings and use a single `print` statement, or use `sys.stdout.write()` instead.

Comment: +1 for how to remove the newline. In Python 3 it's `print("Line 1 is", end="")`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

> A '\n' character is written at the
>   end, unless the print statement ends
>   with a comma. This is the only action
>   if the statement contains just the
>   keyword print.

Answer (score 4):

If you need full control of the bytes written to the output, you might want to use `sys.stdout`

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Line 1 is ")
sys.stdout.write("big!\n")
```

When not outputing a newline (`\n`) you will need to explicitly call flush, for your data to not be buffered, like so:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

this is standard functionality, use `print "foo",`